# 暮らし　and 生活: meaning and usage

Tags: usage, word-usage, synonyms

Are 暮らし　and 生活　interchangeable? For example:

> 日本での暮らし　（is 日本での*生活*　OK?）
>
> 日本の生活に慣れた。（is 日本の*暮らし*に慣れた　OK?)